# Create localhost destination

Tags: sapui5, hana, sap-web-ide

I have some webservices deployed locally and I would like to consume them from my webide instance. I have tried to create the localhost destination but it doesn't work. Its an https services with local certificate deployed locally apache. Is it possible to create a localhost destination ? or should I connect the webservices via cloud connector ?

Comment: You will have to connect them via cloud connector because afaik the requests are proxied by hcp & hcp will not be able to access localhost

Comment: Thanks, another option was accessing them directly via ajax inside the app, but I don't know if it is recommended for production environment

Comment: It's definitely not recommended. Besides it would only work for non oData services